# How to split a string with between different delimiters in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to split a string between for example `<product>` and `</product>`. There are potentially a few thousand products in the string.

Example:

```
<Product xmlns="">
    <Code>021-05402</Code>
</Product>
<Product xmlns="">
    <Code>022-05402</Code>
</Product>
```

I tried an xml parser, but the xml is not well formed and gave lots of errors.

Comment: A 3 year member has had plenty of time to read [Ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: look at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Why not use an .net xml parser?

Comment: I tried an xml parser, however, the xml is not well formed.

Comment: At least post a portion of a sample string....

Comment: I have included a sample

Comment: Can you show a sample including a portion that is not well formed?

Comment: @ShawnVanDenBerg is the XML is not well formed, it will be difficult for us to give you a good answer without also seeing the bad formed.

Comment: You are really going to struggle if you have invalid XML. I would start off by working out _why_ the XML is badly formed.

Comment: The HTML Agility Pack is usually the best answer to dealing with malformed XML-like data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of I would find out *why* the XML is badly formed as this would go a long way to solving your problem in the first place and then you can parse the XML string very easily. As suggested in the comments [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) may be a way forward:

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

Alternatively, something I've had to resort to in the past, you could loop through the string and retrieve values using [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SubString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim xml As String = "<Product xmlns=""> <Code>021-05402</Code> </Product> <Product xmlns=""> <Code>022-05402</Code> </Product>"
Dim startPos As Integer = 0
Dim endPos As Integer = 0

Dim codes As New List(Of String)

While True

    startPos = xml.IndexOf("<Code>", endPos)
    endPos = xml.IndexOf("</Code>", endPos) + 7 '7 is the length of </Code> and I want to include this

    If startPos > 0 Then
        Try
            'would be worth implementing a check that the indexes aren't going to cause a problem
            codes.Add(xml.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos))
        Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
            'Handle the exception
        End Try

    Else
        Exit While
    End If

End While
```

`codes` will contain two items based on your example XML:

```
<Code>021-05402</Code>
<Code>022-05402</Code>
```